# Can you edit the same NSManagedObject in 2 different ManagedObjectContexts and merge their changes?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm syncing with a MySQL database.

Initially, I was going to loop through all my new/modified objects and set all the foreign keys for that object and then do the next object, and so on... But that's a lot of fetch requests.

So instead I wanted to loop through all my new/modified objects and set the foreign keys one at a time. So the first pass over my  objects sets fk1, my next sets fk2, so on...

Cool, fetch requests drastically reduced. Now I'm curious if I could thread these fk setters. They aren't dependent on each other, but they are modifying the same object, even though they're only setting one relationship, and it's a different relationship.  Speaking in git terms, these changes could be 'merged' together without any conflict, but is it possible to push changes in one child managedObjectContext(childContext:save) up to the parentManagedObjectContext(parent:performBlock^{parent:save}) and pull it down in another, different child managedObjectContext(???)? Or will the merge policy only take one childContext's version of the object and leave the other fks effectively unchanged.

I know this exists: NSManagedObjectContext/refreshObject:mergeChanges:

But that's on an object by object level. Will that cause a bunch of fetches? Or will that update my whole context at once/in batches?

Following Apple's suggestion from here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html
I've created/updated my values before I start setting any relationships, so all entities already exist before I try to point any relationships at them.

Aside: We have a couple apps that could benefit from the concurrency, because they throw a considerable amount of data around, and with the quad core iPad apps, this would really help out with the time the initial sync takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'n not sure what you are trying to do and why (you could write less lines in your question and be more clear), but here are some guidelines for working with Core Data:

-- NSManagedObjectContext is not thread safe. Therefore, you need to limit your access to this managed object context to happen inside 1 thread. Otherwise, you may end up having many errors you can't understand.
-- NSManagedObjectContexts apart from doing other things, serve like "snapshots" of your persistent store. That means that when you change an object, you save it to the persistent store, you post a NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and then call mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: in another place inside your program in order to load the latest data from the persistent store. Be careful of thread safety.

NSManagedObjectContext/refreshObject:mergeChanges: according to apple is not about just refreshing a managed object. If you pass YES as the second argument, it will write any pending changes from this managed object context to the persistent store, and will load any other changes to other properties of this object from the persistent store, thus "synchronizing" your object with the persistent store. If you pass NO as the second argument, the object loses any pending changes, and it is being turned to a fault. That means that when you attempt to access it, the Managed Object Context will reload the object as it was last saved to the database. It will NOT reload the entire managed object context. It will only operate on the object.

Aside: I have written a [blog post](http://www.oramind.com/index.php/articles/179-gcd-and-files) that scratches the surface of asynchronous loading from a core data database. In my case, since I'm doing heavy lifting with the database, I ended up using an NSOperation that operates with its own NSManagedObjectContext, and using serial GCD queues to save large chunks of data, since it was faster than having multiple threads accessing the same persistent store, even if they operate on different managed object contexts.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm using block operations, and that's what I was referring to when I said thread. I guess the clarification on how NSManagedObjectContext/refreshObject:mergeChanges: worked is really what I was after. After glancing over your blog post, I may reconsider multithreading the ForeignKey part of my sync since I'm trying to make this as generic as possible and the data model could get pretty complex. I'll comb over it closer later tonight after work. Thanks again.